# Exporting a pretrained model using Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have found plenty of examples for training an object detection model and deploying it using Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine, but what if I want to deploy an existing model from the Tensorflow detection model zoo?

I downloaded ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco and inspected the model using the saved_model_cli. From this output I gather that this model has only one allowed input, an image_tensor.

ML Engine seems to expect 3 inputs:

- image-tensor
- encoded_image_string_tensor
- tf_example_string_tensor

The model zoo repo also indicates that the frozen graphs were generated using v1.12.0 release version of Tensorflow, and that if you want to use a later version you may re-run the exporter. So there seems to be a few reasons you might want to re-export one of the frozen models before deploying to ML Engine.

So my question is, can I use the 'gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training' to do this? And if so, what are the appropriate parameters for this command if I am starting with only the pretrained model which I downloaded from the zoo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I think that due to my own ignorance I was asking the wrong question. It seems that I needed to 1) install the object detection api locally, 2) run export_inference_graph.py and change the input_type to 'encoded_image_string_tensor and finally 3) deploy this re-exported version of the model to ml-engine.

The export:

`python object_detection/export_inference_graph.py   --input_type encoded_image_string_tensor --pipeline_config_path TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt --output_directory for_mlengine`

The deploy:

`$ gsutil cp -r for_mlengine/saved_model/  gs://my_project/my_model`

`$ gcloud ml-engine models create my_model --regions us-central1`

`$ gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 --model my_model  --origin=gs://my_project/my_model/saved_model --framework tensorflow --runtime-version=1.13`